# How to split a version number and assign each number to a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to be able to extract the individual numbers from a version string and assign each value to a variable.

```
echo -en "Please Enter A "$RPM_FILTER" Version Number (e.g. "$VER_EXAMPLE"):"
```

I want to be able to assign for example
1 to `$a`, 16 to `$b` and 0 to `$c` for use in a `sed` filter.

```
Specify Version Number (y/n)? y
Please Enter A Version Number (e.g. 1.16.0): 1.16.0
read -p " " VERSION
```

I am using this currently but this does not work when the individual version number is two digits.

```
declare -i a=$(printf "%s\n" "$VERSION" | cut -c 1)
declare -i b=$(printf "%s\n" "$VERSION" | cut -c 3)
declare -i c=$(printf "%s\n" "$VERSION" | cut -c 5)
```

Comment: `oldifs="$IFS"; IFS=$'.'; read  a b c; IFS="$oldifs"`

Answer (score 3):

You can separate the values in `VERSION` simply by changing the value for `IFS` (*Internal Field Separator*). Make sure you save the old value (default `space`, `tab`, `newline`) and restore `IFS` after you read. Set the new value for `IFS` to `'.'` so bash word-splits on `'.'` for your `read`, e.g.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

printf "Please Enter A Version Number (e.g. 1.16.0): "
oldifs="$IFS"
IFS=$'.'
read a b c
IFS="$oldifs"

printf "%s %s %s\n" $a $b $c
```

(**note:** setting `IFS` can be done as part of the `read` line which avoids having to save the old `IFS` value and restore it when done, e.g. `IFS=$'.' read a b c`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash myscript.sh
Please Enter A Version Number (e.g. 1.16.0): 1.16.0
1 16 0
```

Comment: Very good point. Saves a couple of lines too. (updated with **note**)

Comment: One of the main advantages of this solution is that it is a pure bash solution that does not require any external binaries. Other solutions based on `cut`, `awk`, `sed`, `tr` will call external binaries and will therefore be slightly slower if you process millions of version numbers ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` for this since your common separator is a `.`.

Eg:

```bash
a=$(echo "$VERSION" | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'
b=$(echo "$VERSION" | awk -F'.' '{print $2}'
c=$(echo "$VERSION" | awk -F'.' '{print $3}'
```

I typically find that `awk` syntax to be the most straightforward, but I understand wanting to use `cut`. You're pretty close on your syntax, but you just need to specify a delimiter using `-d`.

Eg:

```bash
a=$(echo "$VERSION" | cut -d'.' -f1)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming OP may want to maintain the input in its original form we can eliminate the half dozen subprocesses (3x `awk/cut`) with a single `IFS/read/here-string` combo:

```
VERSION='1.16.0'                          # result of OP's 'read -p " " VERSION'
IFS=. read -r a b c <<< "${VERSION}"
```

**NOTE:** in this case the `IFS` change is limited to the scope of the `read` call (ie,  no need to save/set/reset `IFS`)

The results:

```
$ typeset -p a b c
declare -- a="1"
declare -- b="16"
declare -- c="0"
```